# How to save codes on VS Code Mac?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code on a Mac to write ReactJS, however I find that I could not save my code. If I use command and s to save, then the JSX will be a mess, just like shown in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM1IR.png)

So how could I solve it? Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your problem, you can't save the file?

Comment: Shouldn't the file extension be `.jsx` in this case?  The auto-formatting rules may change if you correct that.

Comment: Guess your code is saving but only the formatting isn't working, try installing some linter like eslint and see what happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is being saved, but that your code formatting is messing-up your code.

Hit the following combination : **Shift+Command+P**

This will open a menu on top. Inside that menu type **Format Document With...**, and select it. It will allow you to format your code with a different auto-format tool. Choose the one that is appropriate for your code i.e. Prettier.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I use shift+command+p and I change the javascript into javascript react, then the problem is solved! Thank you!